# Get repository content with sbt

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I guess, the following is a basic question. However, I have failed to google it.
There is an URL list of repositories in the file `.sbt\repositories`. Is there a common approach to explore these  repos, to get list of libraries in them.

Comment: What do you ultimately want to do? Listing a repository will give you thousands of artifacts, what would you be looking for?

Comment: @GaëlJ - I have a dependency error and would like to investigate what kind of dependency error I have.

Comment: Repositories usually have web interface to browse or search artifacts, this can be enough. Or maybe share with us your dependency error ;)